# Orange tipped plant found in Carden limestone plains of Ontario

Tags: species-identification, botany

What is species is this plant?

Found in the Carden limestone plains of [Cameron Ranch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ioss.jpg) (near Orillia, Ontario, Canada) on September 9th, 2017.

It is located in an old bog that seems to have sphagnum peat moss (to my untrained eye).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an odd angle, but I think the plant/flower is an [Indian Paintbrush](https://nativeplants.evergreen.ca/search/view-plant.php?ID=02611) (Castilleja coccinea). It is found in Saskatchewan, Manitoba, Ontario, and Nova Scotia.

[image]

Comment: They're in Alberta, as well.